# How to implement undo/redo of audio effects in my audio editor?

Tags: javascript, undo-redo, audioeffect

I got an audio editor project where the user can apply effects like normalize, reverse or compress on the audio file that has been uploaded to the application. I would like to know how undo/redo can be implemented on such functionality's.

Comment: Are you asking about `undo/redo` implementation or about `filterfade()` function; these two has nothing in common.

Comment: @hex494D49 important is undo/redo implementation. but also would like to understand about filterFade().

Comment: @Sanjay we are here to help on specific programming problems. If you are looking for general information, for example, on how `filterfade()` works, then you should better ask Google.

Comment: @honk I am more interested on knowing how to implement undo/redo. I the question is misleading I will edit.

Comment: @Sanjay shortening the question was not a good idea. The code helped to understand how/where you want to apply undo/redo. I suggest that you rollback your edit, because the previous edit was better.